# Are there hypothesis classes that are hard to learn but easy to test?

Tags: machine-learning, property-testing, pac-learning

Let $H$ be a binary hypothesis class, it is easy to see that if $H$ is (efficiently) properly PAC learnable then it is also (efficiently) testable (here we use the standard notion of within or $\epsilon$-far testable).

My question is:

> Fixed a distribution, is there any known hypothesis class that is hard (say NP-hard) to properly learn (to avoid the problem to be trivial, we assume the class is statistically  PAC-learnable) under this specific distribution, but easy (say within polynomial time) to test under the same distribution?

As far as I know most of the results for proving hardness of learning are reduced to the hardness of testing (i.e. decide a gap version of the risk minimization is hard).

Comment: I'll just note that there exist trivial unsatisfying answers (unless I'm misunderstanding the definition). E.g., take H to be the class of all functions. This is trivially testable, since everything is in it! But, it's certainly not learnable.

Comment: @NoahStephens-Davidowitz Yeah, I edited the problem, we now assume H to be statistically PAC-learnable.

Comment: Is this “fixed distribution” easy to sample from?

Comment: @Aryeh I am ssuming it is distribution-free testing-like setting: i.e., you get sample access to the distribution and query access to the function.

Comment: @OP I am a bit confused by your comparison. Typically, testing involves membership queries, while PAC-learning only randomly drawn labelled samples. That hardly seems... "fair."

Comment: So then wouldn't my example below with the 3-term DNF satisfy the OP's criteria?

Comment: Do you want hardness of _improper_ or _proper_ PAC learning? I think it's challenging to show hardness of improper PAC learning, while proper is often easy.

Comment: @Thomas Not necessarily (see my answer). There are results about hardness of learning (information-theoretic), even under the uniform distribution.

Comment: @ClementC. But that’s statistical hardness, not computational hardness, no? The question is for classes that are statistically easy but computationally hard.

Comment: Indeed (cf. comment below my answer).

Comment: @ClementC. So my comment is pointing out that showing _computational_ hardness of _improper_ PAC learning is hard. Computational hardness of proper PAC learning should be easier.

Comment: I agree (sorry, I misinterpreted your earlier comment). @Thomas

Answer (score 3):

Take the class  $\mathcal{M}$ of monotone boolean functions under the uniform distribution on $\{0,1\}^n$:

- it is known that $O(\sqrt{n}/\varepsilon^2)$ queries are sufficient to test it (even with non-adaptive testers) [KhotMinzerSafra15].
- learning $\mathcal{M}$ under the uniform distribution, even allowing membership queries, requires $2^{\Omega(\sqrt{n}/\varepsilon)}$ queries ([BshoutyTamon96,BlaisCOST15]).

Comment: Note: I guess this is not exactly addressing the question, since the class is not *learnable* at all (instead of merely "(presumably) hard to properly learn").

Answer (score 1):

Please define testing precisely (under what distribution? known/unknown?). In the meantime, here is an example of what you may be looking for. Consider the example in the Kearns-Vazirani book, of learning 3-term DNFs. This class of functions is hard to learn properly. But if "testing" involves evaluating a fixed given 3-term DNF on some randomly drawn points -- then sure, that's efficiently doable.

Comment: Yeah, I see. I edited the problem to require the testing and learning under the same distribution (for simplicity one may assume the distribution is known and efficient sampleable).

Comment: *"But if "testing" involves evaluating a fixed given 3-term DNF on some randomly drawn points" * $\leadsto$ what do you mean? Testing involves, given blackbox access to $f$, deciding whether $f$ is a (function represented by a) 3-term DNF, or $\varepsilon$-far (under the ambient distribution) from every such 3-term DNF.